# Finding words from dictionary in input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

The idea behind what I want to do: user types in some kind of text. If his text contains some words (like for an example: "potato", "tomato", "broccoli") then this words get printed. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
words = ["word1", "word2", ... , "word10"]

userInput = input("Type some text")

for word in words:
    if word in userInput:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: Your welcome, feel free to accept answer if this is a working solution,but don't have to :)